# Why the new object created with Object.create() shows empty even with the properties in it?

Tags: javascript

```js
let company = {
  companyName: "DeedaZaib"
}

let emp1 = Object.create(company, {
  name: {
    value: "Hasnain"
  }
})

console.log(emp1.name)
//emp1.name gives => Hasnain
console.log(emp1)
//emp1 gives      => {}
//I expect emp1 to be as {name: 'Hasnain'}
```

I am learning JavaScript from scratch and want to know that where is the ***emp1.name*** stored?

Comment: By default, object properties created as you are creating them are not enumerable, so they don't show up. Add `enumerable: true` to the object properties.

Comment: Your advice worked. Properties are not enumerable in the discussed case but are they enumerable if I assign emp1.name = "Hasnain" instead of assigning it within the Object.create(). Why is that so?

Comment: Well "why?" questions like that are hard to answer, that's just they way the language people decided it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Object.create() is used to create a new object with the specified prototype object and properties and returns a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.

It has 2 parameter the first one is require and new object created from it.

**This method use for inheritance**

```js
function fruits() {
  this.companyName ="DeedaZaib";
}
function func() {
  fruits.call(this);
}

func.prototype = Object.create(fruits.prototype);
const app = new func();

app.name={value: "Hasnain"}

console.log(app);
```